# Why this canvas animation hangs when loaded for a second time with ngRoute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas, ngroute

### Problem

I'm using a [space invaders canvas animation](https://github.com/pjnovas/invaders404) as my 404 not found page. It is working pretty fine when the user is redirected to it for the first time, but the animation hangs if the user is redirected a second time.

### Demo

I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4xAaT0lqWLUdccAriCUY?p=preview) example to show the issue. The page starts at the `/` location loading the home.html. If you click on "Redirect to /404", the location will be changed to `/404` and 404.html will be loaded. The game animation will be running without problems.

However, if you go back to `/` (clicking in the link) and back again to `/404`, the animation will be hanged. Also, the frames-per-second will drop from 60fps to 10fps.

### Code

This demo was built with AngularJS and I switch pages using ngRoute like the following: (nothing special in this)

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }).
    when('/404', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
        controller: '404Ctrl'
    });
```

The home.html contains just instructions and 404.html contains the canvas element:

```
<canvas id="game-canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

The Angular Controller starts the animation calling `initInvaders404();`. This function is defined inside handle-game.js. The game.js completes the canvas animation code that is executed as soon as the 404.html page is loaded.

### What I've already tried

**First guess:** the issue may be related with the canvas being started using its ID. When I recreate the 404.html, the animation is attached with the previous ID but not with the newer ID. To test this, I've created another [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/297F669rSwGYfdGgSUdx?p=preview) and tested another animation (blue rectangle moving) with a similar approach. It is working fine, so maybe that's not the problem.

**Second guess:** the animation code that is attached to the canvas is executed only once, that's why it does not work a second time. To test this, I've placed the game.js and handle-game.js code inside the controller. Unfortunately, same issue. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zenkN7LtPLA0bo2QlSyQ?p=preview)

**Third guess:** ngRoute is messing with the canvas element. To test this, I've placed the canvas element out of the ngView and controlled the ngShow to hide/show the canvas. With this approach, the problem was solved. The `initInvaders404();` can be called multiple times, but it will always focus in the same element and it will never be recreated. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6y7blPzQ8TLXgxs6yepF?p=preview).

### Question

Why this animation can't be executed two times?

**Note1:** I do not want a workaround solution (I've already found one in my third guess). I would like to keep the canvas element inside the 404.html file.

**Note2:** this question is *not* a "please, debug my code" (since game.js have 2000 lines of code). What I want to understand is if there is a canvas property or ngRoute behavior that may cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that it is possible to execute the animation for a second time, but only if the first animation has finished. In this case, after the game finished with an `onWin()` or `onLoose()` event.

When ngRoute changes the view, the canvas element is destroyed, but the game loop still runs in background (as I've confirmed using some `console.log()`). When I try to attach the same game loop to the same canvas id, it hangs.

The workaround used was to catch the `$locationChangeStart` event and stop the animation before the canvas destruction. When I need to execute the game for a second time, it will run: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vx41fsFDUGxoppOABxAv).

Getting the `$locationChangeStart` event:

```
ctrls.controller(
  'MyRootController',
  function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 
        var contains404 = current.includes("404");

        if (contains404) { // if current is 404, next will be something else
          stopInvaders404(); // code to stop the game loop before destroying the canvas
        }
    });
  }
);
```

However, the simplest solution for a third-party animation, which does not involve changing the animation code (as I did with the `stopInvaders404()`) is to place the canvas out of the `ngView` and control its visibility: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6y7blPzQ8TLXgxs6yepF?p=preview).