# req.flash weird behaviour with Angular ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, flash, ngroute

Well, I'm building a simple login page using the MEAN stack. I'm using passport to authenticate, connect-flash to flash messages and Angular ngRoute to, well, *route*. I have the following code:

### **app.js**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.factory("appFactory", function($http) {
  return {
    getData: function(path) {
      return $http.get(path)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        }, function(response) {
          console.log("Error...");
        });
    }
  };
});

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: "homeCtrl",
      resolve: {
        getMessage: function(appFactory) {
          return appFactory.getData("/api/login");
        }
      }
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
});

//to fix!
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope, getMessage) {
  $scope.errors = getMessage.errors;
});
```

### **index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- ngView -->
  <div ng-view></div>
  <!-- /ngView -->
  <script src="/javascript/angular/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### **home.html**

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
  <label>E-mail:</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="email" name="email" />
  <br/>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
<!-- prints error messages (usually, only one) -->
<span ng-repeat="error in errors">{{errors[$index]}}</span>
```

### **login.js**

```js
var passport = require("passport");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get("/api/login", function(req, res) {
    var info = {
      logged: false,
      errors: req.flash("error")
    };

    if (!req.user) {
      console.log(info.errors);
    } else {
      info.logged = true;
    }

    res.json(info);
  });
}
```

### **index.js**

```js
var passport = require("passport");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../views/index.html"));
  });

  app.post("/",
    passport.authenticate("local-login", {
      successRedirect: "/profile",
      failureRedirect: "/",
      failureFlash: true
    }));
}
```

So, I'm testing wrong logins, expecting req.flash() to reset after a refresh on the homepage, but it takes some refreshs before resetting. As you can see, I've put a console check when the api is called falsely, and the console outputs:

```
['Inexistent username!']
['Inexistent username!']
['Inexistent username!']
['Inexistent username!']
['Inexistent username!']
['Inexistent username!']
['Inexistent username!']
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

See? It takes some refreshes before cleaning its value. It has nothing to do with my passport authentication strategy nor anything else but the resolve inside the routing. When I attempt to use it without routes (directly on the controller) it works perfectly. Please, help me enlighten my mind on this one and thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why this canvas animation hangs when loaded for a second time with ngRoute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495103/why-this-canvas-animation-hangs-when-loaded-for-a-second-time-with-ngroute)